# add_action in wordpress using OOP?

Tags: php

I am learning about OOP, and I think I am getting the hang of it. My question is why the author of a wordpress boilerplate plugin wrote the add action function like this

```
add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'admin_init'));
```

According to the codex I understand the `add_action` hook, the paramaters to be passed are `$tag` "The name of the action to which $function_to_add is hooked", and the function that you want hooked `$function_to_add`.

Well I understand the functions in OOP are methods, and I can see why that may change the syntax, but that is just a vague representation, I want a clear answer why the author uses an array, then uses `&$this`. I understand why one would use `$this->property` but not so sure about `&$this`.

Is it just how you refer to the method? If so I still dont understand the array, why wouldnt it look something like `$this->admin_init`.

By the way the structure looks kind of like this

```
    class my_plugin_settings {

            public function __construct() {

                    // register actions
                    add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'admin_init'));

            } 

            public function admin_init() {

                    //Settings here
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&this provides context to the PHP functions under the hood that hook it up to your admin_init function. Check out the declaration of add_action or take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php.

That's how PHP knows to use the function in that object, not a global-level function

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation and link.. I googled this and didnt get any good results because of the ampersand. Ok so (noob question) that makes `&$this` the key and the function `admin_init` the value? I am not sure why the array, and not just saying `$this->funcName`. Going to read up on that hopefully will understand why, but if you know it be great if you could briefly explain :)

Comment: You're passing an array, but it conforms to `callable` type. That's the way callables are structured. If an array is passed, it assumes the key is the object to call and the value is the function. If just a string is passed PHP assumes it's a global level function and calls that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense of it better. There is no other way to write the same syntax? It looks like this `Foo::test` is a way to refer to object/method? This syntax is new, since I assume its only used in OOP, but I am seeing it a lot, now that I am working with OOP.

Comment: There isn't (that I know of), because that's the syntax of a `callable`. Don't forget - you're not passing the function. You're passing a reference to the object and the NAME of the function. PHP uses introspection to figure out which function to actually call. Newer versions of PHP have first class functions, so that may be possible in the future, but for now this is the way to do it.

Comment: Okay that really narrows it down for me, I just saw a reference to that in the php manual it took some scrolling, it also covers extending classes, which might come in handy soon.