# &$this in Wordpress add_action callback

Tags: php, wordpress, reference

I'm just getting my feet wet in Wordpress, and I'm trying to write a very simple plugin using OOP techniques. I've been following this tutorial: http://www.yaconiello.com/blog/how-to-write-wordpress-plugin/ . So far I feel like I understand most of what's going on, but I'm slightly puzzled by statements such as this one:

```
add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
```

Having read the documentation on [Wordpress's add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) and [PHP callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), I gather that the second argument is a method of a class instance. But **I don't understand why `$this` has to be passed by reference**.

Found this note in the PHP docs about callables which I suspect may have something to do with it, but I'm still having a hard time wrapping my head around what the difference is:

> Note: In PHP 4, it was necessary to use a reference to create a callback that points to the actual object, and not a copy of it. For more details, see References Explained.

If I have PHP 5, am I safe just using `array($this,'init')`?

Possibly related: [add_action in wordpress using OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806674/add-action-in-wordpress-using-oop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you are safe to just use `array($this, 'init');`.

What this actually is, is a "callable" in PHP. It will be invoked using `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()` (internally inside the `add_action` method).

PHP's official description of this type of callable:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

You can read more about callables [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Ok, thanks!
I get that it's a callable. Actually I linked to that page in my question ;) Although I referred to it as a callback... guess I better go edit. I just had an academic curiosity about the difference between $this and &$this in this context. Wow, that was a confusing sentence.